# stop web service if I change the criteria search?

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have a web service launched from angular front part.I have date: from and date:to  search criteria.

this is my service angular:

```
downloadEmailAttachmentsByNumber(from: any, to: any) {
return 
 this.httpClient.get('/shared/Modal/getAttachmentsByNumber? 
 from=' + from + '&to=' + to);
 }
```

my web service from spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAttachmentsByNumber", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> getAttachmentsByNumber(
        @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) Long from,
        @RequestParam(value = "to", required = false) Long to) {
    Timestamp fromDate = null;
    Timestamp toDate = null;
    if (from != null) {
        fromDate = new Timestamp(from);
        toDate = new Timestamp(to);
    }
    List<Integer> attachmentsList= this.downloadAttachmentService.getAttachmentsByNumber(fromDate,
            toDate);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(attachmentsList, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

My problem when i change the search criteria from and to ,the web service is still in mode execution with old and the new search criteria:
this is image show that: [image]

how to resolve that? thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create separate service to call your API subscribe it on search & onChange event Simply call unsubscribe() method in life cycle hook,It will stop your service to fetch data  from API